# JQuery sortable on the top <li> only

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm trying to figure out how to tell jquery sortable to only apply to the top most li.

```
<ul id="sortable">
<li id="1">first text
    <ol>
        <li>Just some text
        </li>
        <li>Some more text
            <li>
    </ol>
</li>
<li id="2">second text
</li>
```

I'm trying to populate a hidden field with the sort order based on the "id"

```
function fnOrder() {
        var mSortResultsAry = [];
        $("#sortable li").each(function (index) {
            mSortResultsAry.push(this.id);
        });
        $("[id$=hfResults]").val(mSortResultsAry.join(","));

    }
```

what is happening now is as it goes down the DOM it gets to the

Just some text

and gives it a value of "".  I'd like to get it to only traverse the top most 's

's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [.children()](https://api.jquery.com/children/) of `#sortable`.

```js
var mSortResultsAry = [];

$('#sortable').children().each(function(){
  mSortResultsAry.push(this.id);
});

console.log(mSortResultsAry);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul id="sortable">
  <li id="1">first text
      <ol>
          <li>Just some text
          </li>
          <li>Some more text
              <li>
      </ol>
  </li>
  <li id="2">second text
  </li>
 </ul>
```

Or even search for `<li>`s that have id.

```js
var mSortResultsAry = [];

$('li[id]').each(function(){
  mSortResultsAry.push(this.id);
});

console.log(mSortResultsAry);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul id="sortable">
  <li id="1">first text
      <ol>
          <li>Just some text
          </li>
          <li>Some more text
              <li>
      </ol>
  </li>
  <li id="2">second text
  </li>
 </ul>
```